# Visa on old passport, valid or not

Tags: visas, canada

I am traveling first time to Canada, I have got the visa for Canada stamped on my old passport. Meantime I applied for new passport because it is going to expire in 4 months. Yesterday I received new passport. Today I received POE letter where it is mentioned that if you obtain new passport before your visa expires you will need to apply for new visa.

In this case what shall I do, please advise what can be the solution for this issue.

Comment: You should apply for a new visa, as per the answer on the other question you posted.

Answer (score -3):

If Your old Passport is expired but you have Visa Stamped on it, You have got new Password and you can travel with the new passport. It's not damaged. You don't need to get the visa when you will get the new passport. Just keep holding the old passport. So that you can show them that you have the visa

Further detail, you can check here https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/frequently-asked-questions/about-basics.html

Comment: I'm not sure quoting advice from a completely different government is likely to be either authoritative or helpful.

Comment: I am Indian passport holder, any suggestion how can I transfer my Canada visa on my new passport because as per POE letter I must apply for new visa is I received new passport. Applying new visa will take time. My visa is still valid. Any link or suggestion??